# Creating a collection with single object per class

Tags: java, collections

Is there, in Java, a collection that can be used to store unique-class objects?

For example, I have one parent class (`Parent`) and several child classes (`ChildA`, `ChildB`, and so on) that inherit directly from `Parent`.

Now, I need to store each class' instance in a collection (`Collection<Parent>`). When I add `ChildA` to the collection once, I must not be able add more `ChildA`'s.

I'd like to be able to retrieve each instance by calling `get(ClassB.class)`, and remove it in a similiar manner.

Does there already exist a collection providing that functionality, or do I have to write my own implementation?

Comment: Well, you can always use the `Set`.

Comment: Does ``Set`` allow me to store two different instances of ``ClassA`` in it? That's not what I'm looking for.

Comment: You can create your own class which extends Set(Eg HashSet). Override add() method to incorporate logic of the uniqueness you desire. Iterate over existing collection if object of the class is not present then add else throw runtime exception.

Comment: I don't think there is any in-built implementation of what you need, in Java. You ll have to write your own implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write your own class that uses a `Map<Class<? extends Parent>, Parent>`:

```
private Map<Class<? extends Parent>, Parent> map = new HashMap<>();

public void add(Parent p) {
    if (!map.containsKey(p.getClass()) {
        map.put(p.getClass(), p);
    }
}

public Parent get(Class<? extends Parent> clazz) {
    return map.get(clazz);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

please have a look at HashSet
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html